# How to define your own hash type?

Tags: hashing

Currently Mathematica offers support of a bunch of different hash algorithms. I would like to add my own to the list. In this way I can still use the function `Hash[]`. This allows me to switch between one of Mathematica's predefined algorithms, say `"Keccak512"`, and my own algorithm, say `"Luhn"`.  This is in a similar vein to how Mathematica lets you define your own Random Number Generator.
1. Is this even possible?
2. If so, can someone provide an example?

Comment: I'm about to write my own Luhn algorithm implementation, but would prefer to borrow yours. Care to share it?

Comment: I don't suggest using any thing I write without vetting that it's up to your standards first. But it's top notch compared to the majority of the stuff I write! lol. How do I share it? It's too long for the character length there.

Comment: Sawilkus@gmail.com will work.

Comment: @StephenWilkus. Just saw your comment. Check your email.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Unprotect[Hash];

Hash[str_String, "MyType"] := Mod[Total[ToCharacterCode[str]], 307]
```

Example:

```
In[575]:= Hash["3wrt", "MyType"]

(* Out[575]= 93 *)
```

Comment: I forgot you can unprotect Mathematica's functions. Moreover I did not know you could use Unprotect[] to achieve something to this effect. This works for me. I'm sure I'll keep this in mind down the road for creating other solutions as well. Thanks!

Comment: Daniel, do you need to use `Unprotect` here, or could you do something with `TagSet` to add a hash type?

Comment: @CATrevillian It can be done with `TagSetDelayed` if the second arg is a symbol rather than a string.